# failed to load chats in real time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have created a basic chat application.
it shows the no. of users when u r logged in and u can chat to any of them .
but the problemm is that newly added chats to receiver is not displaying but its added in mysql and also displaying the messages in the sender's side.
plz help me with this....

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Live Table Data Edit</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <h3 align="center">You Are : <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></h3><br />  
                     <div id="live_data"></div>                 
                </div>  
          <div id="messages"></div> 
          <div class="area" style="display:none">
              <textarea id="text" name="text"></textarea>
              <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" value="Send" />
          </div>
           </div>  
      
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      function fetch_data()  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"select.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#live_data').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }  
      fetch_data();  
 
      $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function(){  
           var id=$(this).data("id1");  
     fetch_chat();
         function fetch_chat()  
     {  
      $.ajax({  
      url:"fetch_chat.php",  
      method:"POST",  
      data:{id:id},  
      dataType:"text",  
      success:function(data){  
      $('#messages').html(data);  
      $("div.area").show();
      }   
     
       });  
     }  
     
      
     $("#sub").off("click").on("click", function() {
     var text= $("#text").val();
     $.post('insert_chat.php',{id:id,msg:text},function(data){
     $("#messages").append(data);
     $("#text").val('');
      });
    });

      });  
 });  
 </script>
```